# Filesystem still has errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, filesystems, fsck

I tried to repair filesystem in my Linux machine with

`sudo fsck -y /dev/sda`

but it took too much time and I got error, the error is something about EXT4, so I have an USB in which there is the Kali Linux live. I booted my machine with this USB and I tried again with the command `sudo fsck -y /dev/sda/` and this time it took too much time but without errors. But at the end i got this message:

```
Pedding at end of inode bitmab is not set. Fix, yes
Pedding at end of inode bitmab is not set. Fix, yes
Error writing file system info: Input/output error
/: **** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED ****
/: ********** Filesystem still has errors **********
```

Comment: My first guess would be that `/dev/sda` is the stick you booted from but I don't think your question contains enough details to really say. The full error message with "something about ext4" would be a good start.

Comment: Separately, using Kali for anything else than penetration testing is basically "you are holding it wrong".

Comment: @tripleee what I wanna to know is:  1/ if the fsck repair the filesystem or no?  2/ How can I repair file system? 3/ Is my HDD is corrupted physically?

Answer (score 0):

*Note that in general it is not safe to run e2fsck on mounted filesystems.*

If I have serious filesystem issue I always take a different HDD and **dd** everything from the failing disk to a spare one.

I take my live Linux USB and boot it (it leaves the failing disk alone completely) and start to work on the physical disk like this:

1.) Check the filesystem on your disk (e.g. /dev/sda1 )

```
fsck.ext4 /dev/sda1
```

please read this: https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck.ext4

and this: https://www.tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux/

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved :)